# How do I share Google Maps directions?

Tags: google-maps

I am finding the new Google Maps is confusing. Sharing directions used to be intuitive -- there used to be a "Link" button, and you could even hit the "Short URL" checkbox to access a convenient shortened link. Now, I've entered an origin and destination, and I've been given directions, but I don't know how to share these directions.

Can I just copy/paste the URL of the webpage with the route?

Where is the "Share directions" button? How do I give a friend these directions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 1. When you're ready to share, click the settings gear icon [image: gear]. in the bottom right.
>      If you don't see the settings gear icon [image: gear], see the [alternate instructions](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/144361?ctx=500#classic) at the bottom of this page.
> 2. Select **Share and embed the map**.
> 3. [Optional] Check the box next to "Short URL" to create a shorter link.
> 4. Double-click the link to highlight it, then copy it by pressing **CTRL+C** (for PC) or **⌘+C** (for Mac).
> 5. Paste the link by pressing **CTRL+V** (for PC) or **⌘+V** (for Mac) wherever you want to share the map, like an email or Google+ post.
>
> [image]

[Source](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/144361).

Comment: Your "Source" link seems to point to an unrelated resource. Also, I think [the answer by user64332](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/58732/53755) is the best fit to what the OP was asking for.

Answer (score 2):

i just ran into this same issue.  To share the address, you can click the settings(gear) icon in the bottom right and there's an option to share the location.  It also includes a button for the short URL.

Comment: Bravo - this is the best answer and most closely mimics what was possible in the older maps.

Answer (score -2):

Go to "list all steps," and you will see the old list we all loved.

Comment: You seem to have missed the point of the question entirely.